# Accessing LWC JavaScript files in Visualforce pages

Tags: visualforce, javascript, lightning-web-components

Imagine I have a JavaScript file `common.js`

```
const myMethod = (arg) => {
     // do stuff
}

export {
    myMethod 
};
```

And I include it into a LWC:

```
import { LightningElement } from 'lwc';
import { myMethod } from 'c/common';

export default class MyLWC extends LightningElement {

    handleEvent() {
        myMethod('an example argument');
    }
}
```

I'd like to know how could I can also use `common.js` in a `Visualforce` page?

```
<apex:page applyHtmlTag="false" applyBodyTag="false" showHeader="false" showChat="false" standardStylesheets="false" sideBar="false"
docType="html-5.0">
    <html>
        <head>
             // What can I reference here?
             <script src="... what is the path to common.js ...."></script>
        </head>
        <body>
            // content
        </body>
    </html>
</apex:page>
```

**Questions**

1. What is the path to `common.js` from a `Visualforce` page?
2. Is it even possible to access it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is it even possible to access it?

No, it's not possible. The Content Security Policy shouldn't allow it, as far as I can tell, and the path to the files are not documented and could change between releases. In addition, the code is transpiled by the system when they load, so a LWC script may not be directly compatible with non-LWC code anyways.

If you want to have a common script between Visualforce, LWC, and/or Aura, upload it as a Static Resource and use the appropriate method to import the script (apex:includeScript, ltng:require, loadScript).